# Android: Load own stylesheet in Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I have a question. Is it possible to load my own CSS stylesheet when opening a page with just HTML in Chrome Custom Tabs? So the page has just plain HTML and I would like to apply my own styles.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Tabs doesn't allow the host application to read or write to the DOM of the web content it renders.